# Does the Ubuntu 14.10 ISO file have the option to make a partition?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

does the Ubuntu 14.10 ISO file have the option to make a partition? because I want to try and burn the iso file to the disc and install it that way, and I want to make sure it has that option, and that I wont instead wipe out my windows.

EDIT: I just want to create a partition with ubuntu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

You totally confuse things. It is *your* task, not the ISO's, to copy to the proper partiton. Additionally, if you just copy ISO to HDD into partition, you will need a manual and highly non-trivial installation of bootloader to start it. Even if you succeed, you will have a read-only installation, that keeps all files in memory and reverts to pristine condition on every reboot.
What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

During installation you can choose whether to install Ubuntu alongside Windows or you can make partitions by yourself. It is possible to install Ubuntu without destroying Windows and afterwards you will be able to use both systems on your computer providing that you do everything right.

Please see the links:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

http://www.ehow.com/how_6545352_dual-boot-ubuntu.html

http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/tired-of-windows-8-how-to-dual-boot-windows-ubuntu/